# Not able to install gcc in fedora 16

Tags: gcc, fedora

I'm trying to install gcc in fedora 16 and I'm facing the following issue.

```
[root@fedora ~]yum install gcc
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-   transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.6.3-2.fc16 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp = 4.6.3-2.fc16 for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.6.3-2.fc16 for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cloog-ppl >= 0.15 for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: binutils >= 2.20.51.0.2-12 for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.21.53.0.1-6.fc16 will be installed
---> Package cloog-ppl.x86_64 0:0.15.11-1.fc16 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libppl_c.so.4()(64bit) for package: cloog- ppl-0.15.11-1.fc16.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libppl.so.9()(64bit) for package: cloog-ppl-0.15.11-1.fc16.x86_64
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.6.3-2.fc16 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.14.90-24.fc16.9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.14.90-24.fc16.9 for package: glibc-devel-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.14.90-24.fc16.9 for package: glibc-devel-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.6.2-1.fc16 will be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.6.3-2.fc16 will be an update
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:0.9-1.fc16 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.14.90-14 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.14.90-14 for package: glibc-common-2.14.90-14.x86_64
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.14.90-24.fc16.9 will be an update
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.14.90-24.fc16.9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64
---> Package ppl.x86_64 0:0.11.2-3.fc16 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpwl.so.5()(64bit) for package: ppl-0.11.2-3.fc16.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.14.90-14 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.14.90-14.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.14.90-14.i686
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.14.90-14 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.6.11-4.fc16 will be installed
---> Package ppl-pwl.x86_64 0:0.11.2-3.fc16 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.1-3.fc16 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64 != glibc-2.14.90-14.i686
Error: Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.1-3.fc16.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.10-4.fc16.x86_64
```

My OS is 64 bit version and I tried with installing glibc i686 version because of this issue.But I'm facing the same issue again.

Comment: Have you tried `yum clean all && yum update && yum install gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

On a 64 bit Fedora system, both 32 bit (ex:`glibc-2.14.90-14.i686`) and 64 bit (ex:`glibc-2.14.90-24.fc16.9.x86_64`)  library must be of the same version.

The solution has already been posted in the Fedora official forum.

> 1. package-cleanup --dupes
> 2. package-cleanup --cleandupes
> 3. yum clean all
> 4. yum update
> 5. yum install gcc